# AzureAD joined computer not able to reach a DNS host(A) record on Windows DNS

Tags: windows, networking, dns, azure-active-directory, windows-server-2012

**Environment (User):**
Windows 10 laptop
AzureAD joined
User in the office
Side note: Majority of our users are domain joined, this user travels alot, so we set him up as AzureAD to see how it would work.

**Environment (Network)**
Firewall controls DHCP, routing, etc. 
DNS is running on DC (windows server 2016); DNS = 192.168.1.10
DC is hosted in Azure (connected to on-prem via VPN to firewall)

**Problem:**
This user cant ping host (A) records on the DNS server. The user can ping the FQDN though. e.g. can not ping servername, can ping servername.internal.company.com

This is breaking a service this user needs to run.

All the machines settings for DNS are correctly set (getting pulled through from the firewall). It just seems like the azuread joined device is not able to authenticate to the DC/DNS to retrieve details about a host name, but I find it really weird it can get responses back when using the FQDN of the server?

Can anyone please suggest why this user is getting blocked? I am thinking that becasue this is an AzureAD user their is an authentication issue, any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

recently I have faced the same problem with azure windows VM I have tried all the best possible afford to resolve the issue, but not success finally I have to change the VM IP with azure login panel after restart internet is working.